# How do I use wildcards with qmhandle

Tags: email

I would like to use qmhandle to delete messages based on text in the middle of one of the selectors. For example:

```
qmhandle -Sfailure*
```

will remove all messages where the subject STARTS with "failure". However, if I want to remove all messages with a Subject that CONTAINS "notice" I cannot find a way to do it.

```
qmhandle -S*notice*
```

does not work.

Is there a way to use leading wildcards with qmhandle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes. Working examples:

```
./qmHandle -S"failure notice"
./qmHandle -S"notice"
./qmHandle -S"Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"

  -Stext : delete all messages that have/contain text as Subject
```

You dont need * by default it search for substring.

Comment: I should have seen that in the docs. Now if only I could delete all messages from a specific domain... Apparently it does not work the same for the -f switch. It says I can use regular expressions but I've been unable to get anything to work.